# Monte Carlo in R simulation for Efficiency

Tags: monte-carlo, estimators, efficiency

An exercise displayed in the image below shows example of finding the efficiency of an estimator. I am trying to replicate this example in R using monte carlo. Y1,Y2,Y3 are random samples of normal distribution.
The steps I thought I can take is using  R function would be rnorm() as this function generates random numbers from a normal distribution. I can hard code in the calculation for mu1 and mu2 using the formula given with the three random sample numbers. We can use the randomly generated numbers generated for Y1, Y2, and Y3 and input them into the mu1 and mu2 functions stated in Example 5.4.5. and then find the variance of the two mu functions. We can find the relative efficiency by divide mu1/mu2.

I started off with code with a rnorm of 3:

```
Y <- rnorm(3)
mu1 = 0.25*X[1] + 0.5*X[2] + 0.25*X[3]
mu2 = (1/3)*X[1] + (1/3)*X[2] + (1/3)*X[3]
```

I can further get random deviates with:

```
Y <- replicate(1000,rnorm(3))
```

Would my next step be trying to store each mu1,mu2 to create a 2x1000 matrix? And use that matrix to get the variance through variance function in R?

[image]

Comment: Please type your question as text, do not just post a 
photograph or screenshot (see [here](https://stats.meta.stackexchange.com/a/3176/)). 
When you retype the question, add the [tag:self-study] tag 
& read [its wiki](https://stats.stackexchange.com/tags/self-study/info). 
Then tell us what you understand thus far, what you've 
tried & where you're stuck. We'll provide hints to help 
you get unstuck. Please make these changes as just 
posting your homework & hoping someone will do it for you 
is grounds for closing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am not shure, whether I understood the question correctly but maybe a wrong answer is the best basis for an improved question?

We want 1000 instances of $Y_1$, $Y_2$ and $Y_3$:

```
Y1 <- rnorm(1000)
Y2 <- rnorm(1000)
Y3 <- rnorm(1000)
```

Now we can compute the $\mu$ vectorwise:

```
mu1 <- 0.25*Y1 + 0.5*Y2 + 0.25*Y3
mu2 <- (1/3)*(Y1 + Y2 + Y3)
```

And then variances are

```
var(mu1)
var(mu2)
var(mu1)/var(mu2)   # most of the time, this is larger then 1.0
                    # see histogram constructed in the edit below
```

**Edit:**
It's easy to compute this many times as in

```
hist(replicate(1000, 
               {
                 n <- 1000
                 Y1 <- rnorm(n)
                 Y2 <- rnorm(n)
                 Y3 <- rnorm(n)

                 mu1 <- 0.25*Y1 + 0.5*Y2 + 0.25*Y3
                 mu2 <- (1/3)*(Y1 + Y2 + Y3)

                 var(mu1)/var(mu2)
                 }),
     main ="", xlab = expression(mu[1]/mu[2]),
     breaks = 20)
abline(v = (3/8)/(3/9), lwd = 3, lty = 3)
```

Comment: +1: Great answer. I am just not sure what the comment "#always larger then 1.0" means.

Comment: @ColorStatistics The scan from the book prooves that $Var(\mu_1)$ is larger than $Var(\mu_2)$ so I computed the fraction of `var(mu1)/var(mu2)`. It being larger then $1.0$ shows that $Var(\mu_1) > Var(\mu_2)$. Nothing more.

Comment: @ColorStatistics If this is a great answer, then the question is about programming and thus off topic on this site. In that case, StackOverflow is probably the better place for the question.

Comment: I guess the word "always" threw me off a bit as for an unlucky enough draw, the ratio of the sample variances need not be greater than 1, while, of course, the ratio of the population variances would always be greater than 1.

Comment: I said it is a great answer because I started coding my answer but your vectorized code is much more elegant :). This does seem quite a bit about programming but it is also about understanding sampling and estimators so to me this is a valuable question/answer, but that is just my opinion.

Comment: @ColorStatistics Thank you. I also removd the "always" part.